# Flurry errors report

Tags: android, crash, flurry

My application has been published for a while. I have never received any crash reports through Google play developer page. Then I integrated Flurry to see how the audience is behaving. On Flurry dashboard I saw that my application occasionally crashes. The crashes are irregular and produce very different stack traces. I cannot understand why the crashes appear and I cannot reproduce them on my devices and emulators - application just works perfectly. My problem is that it is difficult to fix something that really works for you :)

Flurry dashboard shows that the crash ratio is 1-2% of the sessions - not that big. So I was thinking just to accept that. But the crashes still bother me in the back of my head. I want your advice - should I accept this small crash ratio or really investigate the crashes? What crash ratios do you have for your applications ?

Answer (score 1):

As for me, it's been impossible to get zero crashes for any app, so my suggestion is learning  to live with it :)

You cannot test your app in all devices and android versions, and even if you would, there may be installed applications conflicting with yours. Imagine for instance you create an app that needs to use the camera, but there's another app installed that doesn't properly release the camera resources; that will surely mess with your app, and there's no much you can do to predict nor change it.

So, just make sure you test your app in as much devices as you can (low, mid and high range), focusing in the most popular devices/android versions (I guess `Flurry` reports which devices are your app installed in)